# sql select records from e.g.the 5th record to the end

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The following is a scope in a model file I would like to complete, to get all records from the 5th record to the end of a table called 'attendees':

scope :waiting_list, -> { where(will_not_attend: false) }

I would very much appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

`Attendee.last(Attendee.count - 5)`

Above code will skip first five records and return rest of the records in `Array`.

And your desired scope will be:

`scope :waiting_list, -> { where(will_not_attend: false).last(Attendee.count - 5) }`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But I need first that all records that have field 'will_not_attend' eq. 'falls' be selected, out of this list select the records beginning e.g. from record number 6 to the end of the list. Sorry if I didn't describe it exactly before.

Comment: I'm not sure if the following correct:
scope :waiting_list, -> { where(will_not_attend: false).offset(event.maximum_attendees + 1) }

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good approach to skip last number of records and then fetch the remaining because there might be new insertions in to the database that leads to invalid records.
Any how you can use `offset` to skip number of rows as per your requirement.

```
scope :waiting_list, -> { where(will_not_attend: false).order(created_at: :asc).offset(Attendee.count - 5) }
```